# Webpack not rendering any markup logic on build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, micro-frontend

I have a microfrontend app with a custom webpack(v5) configuration with react, typescript and the module federation plugin.
Everything works well in develop mode. Also, the built projects works fine when imported and rendered into the microfrontend container app (container app wires together all microfrontend apps).

But, when a build is executed and i try to run the production build locally, using `serve -s dist -p 9997`, i only get a blank page with no markup rendered. (Apologies in advance for the long post):

**webpack build config file**

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx"], // file extensions we allow webpack to evaluate
    },
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            // "@babel/preset-env",
                            "@babel/preset-react",
                            "@babel/preset-typescript",
                        ],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "microfrontend_app", // name of the app used by the container to get the app code
            filename: "remoteEntry.js", // name of the file this app sends to the container - DO NOT CHANGE.
            exposes: {
                "./MicrofrontendApp": "./src/bootstrap", // alias, lets the container app import this app as a module with name PortalNavigationApp
            },
            shared: packageJson.dependencies,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

**webpack dev config file**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx"], // file extensions we allow webpack to evaluate
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9998,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "/index.html",
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            // "@babel/preset-env",
                            "@babel/preset-react",
                            "@babel/preset-typescript",
                        ],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "microfrontend_app", // name of the app used by the container to get the app code
            filename: "remoteEntry.js", // name of the file this app sends to the container - DO NOT CHANGE.
            exposes: {
                "./MicrofrontendApp": "./src/bootstrap", // alias, lets the container app import this app as a module with name PortalNavigationApp
            },
            shared: packageJson.dependencies,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="_microfrontend-app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.tsx**

```
export default ({ history }: IApp): JSX.Element => {
    console.log('loading App.tsx');
    return (
        <MainWrapper>
            <Router history={history as unknown as H.History}>
                <h1>hello from wellcom template app</h1>
            </Router>
        </MainWrapper>
    );
};

const MainWrapper = styled.main``;
```

**bootstrap.tsx**

```
const mount = (
    el: Element,
    {
        onNavigate,
        defaultHistory,
        initialPath,
    }: {
        onNavigate: (() => void) | null;
        defaultHistory: any;
        initialPath: string | null;
    }
): unknown => {
    // if in development and isolation, use browser history. If not, use memory history
    const history =
        defaultHistory ||
        createMemoryHistory({
            initialEntries: [initialPath || ""],
        });
    if (onNavigate) {
        history.listen(onNavigate);
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App history={history} />, el);

    return {
        onParentNavigate({ pathname: nextPathName }: { pathname: string }) {
            const { pathname } = history.location;

            //prevent infinite routing loop
            if (pathname !== nextPathName) {
                history.push(nextPathName);
            }
        },
    };
};

// If we are in development and in isolation call mount immediately
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    const devRoot = document.querySelector("#_microfrontend-app");

    if (devRoot) {
        mount(devRoot, {
            defaultHistory: createBrowserHistory(),
            initialPath: null,
            onNavigate: null,
        });
    }
}

export { mount };
```

**index.ts**

```
import("./bootstrap");
```

This is the output i get when running webpack.dev.js:
[image: Running in dev with webpack.dev]

And this is the output i get after running webpack build and serving using `serve -s dist -p 9997`:
[image: Running in prod with webpack.prod]

I just cannot figure out why this happens. This is the output of my dist folder:

[image]

The index.html correctly appends the main.975.... js file. If i do a CTRL+F looking for "hello from App.tsx" in all the js files, i find it in the 499.63...js. So the markup logic exists in build.

[image]

Also, the main.975 js file seems to be aggregating all other js files:

[image]

I just cannot understand why the markup is not being rendered in the build version? I suspect there is something im missing in the webpack prod file. I tried to search through a create-react-app webpack file to compare, but there is so much stuff there i got completely lost.

Comment: "And this is the output i get after running webpack build and serving using serve -s dist -p 9998"... yet the screenshot below it shows the browser connected to port 9997. Huh?

Comment: Not much aware about it, but can you please check mode: 'production' instead of "development" in webpack dev config file.

Comment: @spender sorry, spelling mistake. Meant of course 9997. Updated.

Comment: @JayeshNaghera, interesting. Changing to production in the config.dev file produces the same error. Changing it back to development makes it render correctly again. The same is true for config.prod; changing it to development makes it render correctly

Comment: @Flimzy_Programmer There are other configuration as well plz refer https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/ it may help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Pretty silly, but in bootstrap.tsx, the mount function is never called if development = 'production'.

So just removing the

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
...
}
```

if check made it work.

Comment: Is prod build working for you? I have very similar code, when I build in production, I have blank screen